# How do I modify data variables that are stored as object properties in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code which I restructured for simplicity and re-usability. My requirement is simple: I have a list of empty arrays which are mapped to certain keys (corresponding to a set of unique ID's).

In order to store data into these n number of arrays, I have a common API call whose request payload would contain the id of the reference data, and then on receiving the response I wish to look up the name of the variable inside the object, corresponding to the ID and store the value there before proceeding to next iteration value/ID

example: if value of id is 1, the request payload will have id as one, and the corresponding response data should be saved into the value of mapped[1] ie. fruits...  (the array named "fruits" given above, and not the object value, how do I do that?)

```
let fruits=[]
let vegetables=[]
let nuts=[] ......etc upto n number of entries

let mapped={1:fruits,2:vegetables,3:nuts,.......(other 'n' entries) }

for(let i=1;i<=15;i++){
    let payload={id:i}
   this.apiService.fetchReferenceData(payload).then((response)=>{
         mapped[i]=response.data  //the value I receive here needs to be stored into the array matching the name of the object value
    })

  }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve here? do you want for example if `mapped[i]` is `fruits` then store `response.data` in the fruits variable(which you defined like let fruits=[])?

Answer (score 1):

Jay Swamianrayan!

Everything else looks fine... Perhaps what you are looking for is...

```
mapped[i].push(response.data)
```

instead of

```
mapped[i]=response.data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array method like `push` to store the value inside the array.

So instead of using -  `mapped[i]=response.data`, use can use  `mapped[i].push(response.data)`

P.S: Based on the code you provided I am assuming that you are storing the reference of each array(fruits, vegetables, and so on) inside the `mapped` object.